# How do you use the trello api to add a new card in Python?

Tags: python, trello

I'm having a problem with the python trello api.

**Context:** - I'm trying to add a new card with the trello api in a particular position in a list.

**Problem:** - I can create a new card, but I can't add it to a particular position into the trello list.

**Code:**

```
from trello import Lists
clientTrello = Lists(
    apikey=key
    token=token
)
clientTrello.new_card(listID, "Title", None, "Desc")
```

Any solutions/suggestions you can give would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do this.

[note: there are a couple of python Trello API wrappers.  Below is using this one https://github.com/tghw/trello-py]

```
from trello import TrelloApi

TRELLO_APP_KEY = ""     #your trello key
TOKEN = ""              #your api token
listID = ""             #the id for your list 
cardPos = "top"         #'top', 'bottom', or a number

trello = TrelloApi(TRELLO_APP_KEY, TOKEN)
newCard = trello.cards.new("My Card", idList=listID, desc="my card description", pos=cardPos)

print(newCard)    #above returns json details of the card just created
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately I don't know how to help you using the Python API, but if you take a look at the [Trello Api](https://developers.trello.com/reference#cardsid-2) it is possible to use the cards endpoint to achieve this - one of the query params is `pos`.